# MLE for model parameters of a bivariate random variable sample with a given density function

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, computational-statistics, density-estimation

so this is a statistical computation question.

I have a data sample (X,Y) and a given density function of this sample that depends X and Y given mean of X, mean of Y and theta. I need to run an MLE for the model parameters. How do I approach this in R? I was thinking to use Newton-Ralphson algorithm but I've never seen it being done for 3 parameters for given density function...

Answer (score 0):

R and its packages has many functions for optimization. In this example, I used `stats4::MLE()` with method "BFGS" (quasi-Newton method).

Example data

```
set.seed(1); df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(30, mean = 10), Y = rnorm(30, mean = 5))
```

(1) If R doesn't have the density function, you need to make it.

```
dnorm.f <- function(x, mu, s) 1 / (sqrt(2 * pi * s^2) ) * exp(-(x - mu)^2 / (2 * s^2))
  ## R has dnorm function, so if it is normal distribution, actually you needn't make it
```

(2) make a function to calculate a negative log-likelihood. Arguments of this function are target paramaters (`abs(s)` is a countermeasure against errors).

```
mle.f <- function(muX, muY, s)  -(sum(log(dnorm.f(x, muX, abs(s)))) + sum(log(dnorm.f(y, muY, abs(s)))))
  # using R function ver # mle.f <- function(muX, muY, s) -(sum(dnorm(x, muX, abs(s), log = T)) + sum(dnorm(y, muY, abs(s), log = T)))
```

(3) search paramaters minimizing an output of (2)

```
x <- df$X
y <- df$Y

library(stats4)
result <- mle(mle.f, start = list(muX = mean(x), muY = mean(y), s = 1), method = "BFGS")
summary(result)
```